# how to remove default value in date picker WFFM

Tags: wffm

WFFM has a date picker with default value in it, i want to make form that didn't display any values when load for the first time. Im thinking about making the `val('')` in custom script:

```
$scw(document).ready(function(){
    $scw("#Vg-0a47Mo0irbuy6Osdada_Sections_0__Fields_6__Value").val('');
});
```

But if i clicked submit and there is still other field error, it erase the value of date picker.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol i finally found a way. If you didnt want to make custom field and you are sure that your datepicker default value will be empty on all your WFFM form.
The easiest way is to changed it in **datepickerfield.cshtml** by editing:

```
 @Html.TextBox("Value", currentDate.ToString(Model.DateFormat), new { @readonly = "", @class = "field-datepicker" })
```

to:

```
 @Html.TextBox("Value", null, new { @readonly = "", @class = "field-datepicker" })
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value of the date picker field is set in the `Text` property. The easiest way to set the default value to be an empty string is to manually add an empty `<Text></Text>` parameter in the `Parameters` field of your date picker form field item, in Sitecore:

[image]

Comment: fyi im using WFFM 8.0, Ive tried your solution, but the default value didnt change into empty string instead it changed to current date. Thanks

Comment: I tested it only using a WFFM WebForms form, not for MVC. I am glad you found a better solution.